# How to implement video-streaming/ chunked encoding with Azure Blob Storage in PHP?

Tags: php, azure, video-streaming, azure-blob-storage, slim

I try to setup a php api that is able to stream a ".mp4" video coming from Azure Blob Storage. 
What i want to achieve is, that not the whole video must be downloaded before the video starts. 
I'm using Slim Framework 3 for my Rest-API.

I've already implemented "normal" video playback, but it takes very long until the video actually starts playing.
I am using the Azure Storage for PHP Sdk to access the Blob storage, then i get the blob and use "fpassthru" to write the video in the http response.
Additionally i set the "content-type" and "content-length" header.

```
$blob = $this->blobClient->getBlob($this->ContainerName, $filename);
fpassthru($blob->getContentStream());
$response = $response->withHeader('Content-type', 'video/mp4');
```

Right now it takes a very long time until the (about 30 mb) video starts playing, because all the data must be downloaded before the video begins.
I would like to know if it's possible to enable a sort of "chunked" playback, that starts when a part of the video data has already arrived.

Comment: You might want to look in to [Azure Media Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/media-services/)

Comment: Yes of courde Azure Media Services would be the allround Streaming solution. But i thought maybe this is a bit of an overkill and probably there would be an easy solution to implement just the chunked video playback. But it doesn't seem so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way would be to stream your video using an [HLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming)([RFC 8216](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8216)) implementation.

It won't be simple, as you'll need to:

- Provide an endpoint for getting index files
- Breakdown your mp4 file into smaller chunks that can be downloaded separately by **HLS** supporting players (I think most ones do this days)
- Might need to manage the chunks internally, as breaking the mp4's each time a user request the video (or part of it) is very inefficient.

Also, you might want to take a look at something like [hls-video-generater](https://packagist.org/packages/mehrdad-dadkhah/hls-video-generater) , or any other alternative you might find.

**Update**

If you're already using **Azure**, I would suggest you take a look at [Media Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/media-services/), it should give you what you want with very little effort.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, but i think my PHP skills are not sufficient enough to implement a HLS solution on my own. The libary looks great, but i'm not sure if it's not possible to combine this with with Azure Blob Storage, because each video would have to be encoded then uploaded again on the blob storage. But after that, how do i access azure blob storage correctly so that this time, the video gets streamed and not downloaded?

Comment: Talking about HLS, although the video **feels** like a smooth stream, the player actually downloads the chunks and starts playing each chunk only once it's been downloaded. The difference is that the chunks are (usually) significantly smaller than the complete video file. And see my update on a possible alternative.

Comment: Yes i think i will go with Azure Media Services then. Thank you very much for the explanation.